# negating characters in C

Tags: c

Is this undefined behavior?
It prints `-128` as the result:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char i=-128;
    i=-i;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Please explain.

Comment: Datatype `signed char` is not capable of holding the number 128. Its range is -128 to 127.

Comment: Why is this question being upvoted? This is CS101 and was asked hundreds of times already.

Comment: @skynorth: If you can provide a link to a question this duplicates, I'll vote to close.

Comment: @FredLarson - I am actually starting to read that signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C. Can you confirm? http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2009-June/001235.html

Comment: @skynorth: No, it's implementation defined behavior. Look at [ouah's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11058380/10077).

Answer (score 8):

The two's complement of -128 in an 8-bit signed value is -128.

Look at the binary values:

Original value: 10000000

Complement:     01111111

Increment:      10000000

Comment: @EitanT Look up the definition of Two's Complement.

Comment: @EitanT: Two's complement is a complement and an increment. Just a complement is a one's complement.

Comment: C does not guarantee the result to be `-128` see 6.3.1.3p3 in C99.

Comment: another way to look at it, is if you take `x = 10000000b` and add 128 to it, i.e. `100000000b`, you will get `100000000b`, which when cast to an 8 bit value, gives you `00000000b`, so `x + 128 = 0`, therefore `x = -128`.

Comment: Ah okay. I wasn't following you at first.

Comment: @ouah: Correct, I don't believe C specifies two's complement. In practice, however, I think the vast majority of machines use it.

Comment: @FredLarson I agree this is the commonly implemented implementation behavior.

Comment: This answer is NOT what's happening in the C code. The negation is applied to an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: @R..: It doesn't make that much difference. There's a sign extension, but the process is the same.

Comment: There is no complement or increment in OP's code, and nothing funny happens during the negation either. The only unexpected (i.e. not determined by normal integer arithmetic) operation happens when the `int` is converted down to `char` via an implementation-defined conversion.

Answer (score 4):

This is not undefined behavior. Assuming type `char` is signed in your platform, it is implementation defined behavior. (C99, 6.3.1.3p3)

`i = -i`;

the `i` in `-i` is first promoted to `int`, so `-i` is `128` and then `128` is converted to `char` by the integer conversions.

Here is the paragraph of the Standard that says the conversion of `128` to `char` is implementation defined:

> (C99, 6.3.1.3p3) Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
>   represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or       an implementation-defined signal is raised.

**EDIT**: while it is implementation defined, there is a common implementation behavior between most implementations. Here is what `gcc` (and most other compilers do) documents to do:

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be             within range of the type; no signal is raised

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html

Note that not all compilers behave this way. Some (DSP) compilers just saturate. In this case (and still assuming a signed `char`), after `i = -i;` the value of `i` would be `127`.

Comment: does the size of char i gets change.if not how could it retain the result 128

Comment: in `-i` the value of `i` not the object is promoted to `int`. So the assignment which is done is actually: `i = 128` which is an implementation defined conversion when `i` is a `signed char`.

Comment: @ouah please explain what do you mean by implementation defined conversion

Comment: @cdummy it means the compiler can choose the algorithm and the kind of conversion that is performed and the compiler has to document it in the compiler documentation.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer among a bunch of upvoted answers that are "less than correct". :-)

Answer (score 1):

[2's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

-128 = 0b10000000

So you want to find: -(-128):

### Step 1 (negate):

`~(-128) = 0b01111111`

### Step 2 (add 1):

`0b01111111 + 0b1 = 0b10000000 = -128`

So with an 8 bit number, -(-128) = -128!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a signed char. The maximum of a signed positive single byte is 127. By negating -128 to attempt to get to +128 you end up overflowing to -128. This behaviour may well be OS and compiler dependent.

Comment: i = -i is equivalent to i = -1 * i;    The intent is that the result be +128.

Comment: You're right, I see your point now, it's negating rather than adding. I read it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not undefined behavior.

Multiplication by -1 is equivilant to negating the bits and then adding 1. Thus, you are really doing,

```
~10000000+1 = 01111111+1 = 10000000
```

which is still `-128`.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood so you say there is no integer promotion

Comment: @paulsm4, no, multiplication (isn't that what I meant?). `i = -i` <==> `i = -1*i`?

Comment: @cdummy, what is "integer promotion"?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same results.

Here's the assembly (Microsoft Visual Studio):

```
; File tmp.c
; Line 5
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
; Line 6
    mov BYTE PTR _i$[ebp], -128         ; ffffff80H
; Line 7
    movsx   eax, BYTE PTR _i$[ebp]
    neg eax
    mov BYTE PTR _i$[ebp], al
; Line 8
    movsx   ecx, BYTE PTR _i$[ebp]
    push    ecx
    push    OFFSET FLAT:$SG775
    call    _printf
    add esp, 8
; Line 9
    xor eax, eax
; Line 10
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
```

Note the binary value.

And remember your "twos complement" arithmetic.

Does it make sense?

======  ADDENDUM  ======

This is really, really simple.  Here's a slightly modified example that might help clarify:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=-128, j, k, l;
  char c = i;
  printf("i: %d == 0x%x; c: %d == 0x%x\n", i, i, c,c);

  j=-i;
  k=~i;
  l=0-i;
  i=-i;
  c=-c;
  printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",i,j,k,l,c);
  printf("0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x\n",i,j,k,l,c);
  return 0;
}
```

RESULTS:

```
i: -128 == 0xffffff80; c: -128 == 0xffffff80
128, 128, 127, 128, -128
0x80, 0x80, 0x7f, 0x80, 0xffffff80
```